# Get error in swift after convert into latest version

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

While I am trying to convert my application in to latest swift version, I face error: `"Could not find overload for '==' that accept the supplied argument"` on execution of below code line: 
it seems issue is regarding my array definition

```
var ArrayOne:NSArray!
ArrayOne = jpgArray.filterArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "self CONTAINS 'WATCH')) as NSArray!
    let array:Array = segmentControl?.selectedSegmentIndex==0 ? ArrayOne! : segmentControl?.selectedSegmentIndex==1 ? arrayTwo! : arrayThree!
```

Can anyone help me for same?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let array:Array = (segmentControl?.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) ? arrayOne! : (segmentControl?.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) ? arrayTwo! : arrayThree!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you have whitespaces at the **right** places:

```
let array:Array = segmentControl?.selectedSegmentIndex==0 ? arrayOne! : segmentControl?.selectedSegmentIndex==1 ? arrayTwo! : arrayThree!
```

That means:

- one whitespace after `==0`
- no whitespace in `arrayOne !`